# My UI lags When I fetch contacts in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am displaying the list of contacts from my phonebook inside my app and the result is working fine but there is a 5-6 seconds UI lag. It happens only on my real device which I believe is due to large number of contacts saved on my device.

Kindly help with how I can offload UI building from the main logic.

Upon loading the screen, I am triggering the contacts using async function

```
@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getContacts();
}

getContacts() async {
    contacts = ContactsController.getContacts();
}
```

Now Contacts are fetched using the below logic

```
import 'package:fast_contacts/fast_contacts.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

static Future<List<Contact>> getContacts() async {
    bool isGranted = await getPermission();

    if (isGranted) {
      try {
        List<ContactField> fields = [
          ContactField.displayName,
          ContactField.phoneNumbers,
        ];
        List<Contact> contacts = await FastContacts.getAllContacts(
          fields: fields,
        );
        contacts.sort((a, b) => a.displayName.compareTo(b.displayName));
        return contacts;
      } catch (e) {
        log.d("$className: GetContacts(): Failed to get contacts");
      }
    }
    log.d("$className: GetContacts(): Failed to get contacts");

    return [];
  }
```

Below is the UI building, Which I am using.

```
_buildContactsCardList(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<Contact>>(
      future: contacts,
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return const Center(
            child: Text("Error Fetching Contacts! Check Permissions",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  fontSize: 16,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                )),
          );
        }
        if (snapshot.data == null) {
          return const Center(
            child: SizedBox(height: 50, child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
          );
        }

        if (snapshot.data.length == 0) {
          return const Center(
            child:
                SizedBox(height: 50, child: Text("Contacts Permission Denied")),
          );
        }
        return ListView.separated(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            primary: false,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
            separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Divider(
                color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                thickness: 1,
              );
            },
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              Contact contact = snapshot.data![index];
              return AddFriendLineItemWidget(
                  user: OnboardingUser.fromContacts(contact),
                  isContact: true,
                  isFriend: false,
                  loggedInUser: currentUser);
            });
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Flutter, everything is executed in a single thread.
In your case, your UI and **getContacts()** are processing on your main thread. But the **getContacts()** is enough expensive and it makes busy the main thread. To avoid the problem you need to use MultiThread for the **getContacts()** method so that it could not hamper the main thread and UI can use the main thread and run without lag.

You need a clear idea about **Threading**. For that I suggest some resource that can help you.

Read

1. https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-threading-5c3a7b0c065f
2. https://pub.dev/packages/threading
3. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yUMjt0AxVHU&t=46s&ab_channel=Flutter